# queryPedometerData function not execute from widget

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

I am using CMPedomer to collect Steps data.

```
if CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() {
    print("Step counting is available...")

    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())
    let endDate = Date()

    CMPedometer().queryPedometerData(from: beforeDate!, to: Date()) { [weak self] (data, error) in
        print("Handler (data):")
        
        guard let activityData = data, error == nil else {
            
            print("There was an error getting the data: \(error!)")
                        
            return
        }
    
    todayStepCount = Int(truncating: activityData.numberOfSteps )
    todayDistanceCount = Double(truncating: activityData.distance ?? 0.0)
    todayFloorCount = Int(truncating: activityData.floorsAscended ?? 0)
    
    print(activityData)
    }
}
```

this function works fine from main app. Did not works from Widget.

I debug the widget. this queryPedometerData being called but did not enter this function and print nothing.

```
CMPedometer().queryPedometerData(from: beforeDate!, to: Date()) { [weak self] (data, error) in
```